# Prove this trigonometry inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I'm having difficulty proving that tan(26°) < 0.5 < tan(27°) . Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: trying to prove the left side first, I get : 2sin26-sin64 < 0  .. not much more than this.

Comment: What are the restrictions? (1) can we use calculator to find arctan(0.5)? (2) If not, can we use protractor to measure the smallest angle of the 1-2-√5 right-angled triangle?If yes to either one of the above, that angle is 26.xxxx degrees. Result follows from the fact that tangent is an increasing function. The above is not a vigorous proof but is an "idea".

Comment: It is not even a proof. But the 1-2-√5 right-angled triangle leads us to think of the golden ratio.

Comment: the idea behind this problem, is not trying to use the calculator, or considering it not to be a proof. Since it's not obvious and the two sides can not be compared directly, it remains to be proved . I got it solved using simple trigonometry formulas. However thank you for your replies.

Comment: One approach would be to take the arctangent of all three terms, then transform degrees into radians, and expand the middle term using the [Taylor series for the arctangent function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions).

Comment: @arblitr06 Glad to learn that you have the problem solved. Like to share your finding by answering your own question?

Comment: @Mick  .. answer shared.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the solution. Feel free to ask if you don't understand any of the steps.

Let's first prove the left side of the inequality:

$\tan26 < \frac{1}{2}  \Rightarrow 2sin26<cos26 \Rightarrow 4sin^2{26}<cos^2{26}$

$\Rightarrow 4sin^2{26} < 1-sin^2{26} \Rightarrow sin^2{26}<\frac{1}{5} \Rightarrow cos^2{52}>\frac{3}{5} \Rightarrow cos^2{52}>\frac{9}{25} $

$\Rightarrow cos104>\frac{-7}{25} \Rightarrow sin14< \frac{7}{25}$ ---    But sin14 < sin15

also $sin\frac{\pi}{12}<\frac{\pi}{12}<\frac{7}{25} \Rightarrow\Rightarrow tan26<\frac{1}{2}$

Now let's prove the right side :

$tan27>\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow 4sin^2{27}>cos^2{27} \Rightarrow sin^2{27}>\frac{1}{5}$

$\Rightarrow cos54<\frac{3}{5} \Rightarrow sin36<{3}{5} \Rightarrow sin^2{36}<\frac{9}{25} \Rightarrow cos72>\frac{7}{25} \Rightarrow sin18>\frac{7}{25}$

But  $sin18=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4} > \frac{1.2}{4} > \frac{7}{25}$

So $sin18>\frac{7}{25} \Rightarrow \Rightarrow tan27>\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Good work. Some typos found. (1) should be cos 52 > 3/5 instead of ... (2) should be sin 36 < 3/5 instead of sin 36 < 35.